# Detect Blue screen occurrence

Tags: windows, hardware

How to detect whether blue screen occurred or not on windows 7 32bit OS. One way is to check for \windows\memroy.dmp and \windows\Minidmp*.dmp files. Is there any other place we can check to see if blue screen occurred. Event viewer logs doesn't seems to record all the blue screens occurrence. Any thoughts on this?

EDIT: The OS is win7 32bit (OS customized to 900MB size by removing the most of the components). The languages supported are C++ without using the .NET framework and VB script/java script.

I need to extend this to Win 7 64bit and Vista 32 bit also.

EDIT2: If system comes back event viewer logs the BSOD irrespective of the BSOD type? If yes, is there any list of event ID I can look in event viewer logs?

Comment: Which language are you writing this code in?

Comment: The OS is win7 32bit (OS customized to 900MB size by removing the most of the components). The languages supported are C++ without using the .NET framework and VB script/java script.

Answer (score 3):

It depends whether you can configure by yourself how blue screens are recorded.

If you can, the event viewer seems the best way. If it's configured, there should be an entry for each BSOD.

Here is some detailed information on [How to configure system failure and recovery options in Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307973/en)

Comment: Thanks. But event viewer logs doesn't record all the BSOD errors if catastrophic hardware failure occurs.

Comment: When the system comes back, it should, if it's capable. Of course if the machine is destroyed, nothing will record anything ... but no program will be able to run either.

Comment: Simon - Thanks. So If system comes back event viewer logs the BSOD irrespective of the BSOD type? If yes, is there any list of event ID I can look in event viewer logs?

Comment: I believe the BSOD is **Source**: System, **Category**: (102), **Type**: Error and **Event ID**: 1003

Comment: Thanks. Is Event ID 1003 covers all possible BSOD errors? I tried to generate BSOD with "CrashOnCtrlScroll" method and it generated Event 41 (Critical, Kernel Power) and no Event ID 1003. I am unable find possible event ID list for BSOD at internet, do you have any info on it?

Comment: Nope. You could ask on MSDN forums, but I don't think this is documented anywhere. 41 seems to be new to Windows 7 and there could be others. The best is probably to write your app so you can configure new numbers in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Search backwards in the log for the most recent startup event and the secondmost recent startup event.  If there's no shutdown event in between them, then you know.

Comment: Thanks. But we are running test package which reboots OS so many times. Is there any list of events I can check. Event 41 is one the of the event for improper shutdown, but I want the all possible event ID incase BSOD occurred.